# 13'' Mid-2012 Pro, can I use FireWire to VGA for a triple screen setup?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, vga-adapter, firewire

I have a [mid-2012 13'' Macbook Pro](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp649). I'm currently using a Thunderbolt to VGA to use a second monitor.

I'm feeling myself in need for a third monitor for my work. I was wondering if it was possible to use a [Firewire to VGA adapter](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=firewire%20to%20vga&oq=firewire%20to%20vg&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.3483j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8%E2%89%88) to plug in a third screen?

I'm worried that my Macbook can only support 2 screens, and even if it could support three, I'm not sure I can do that with the Firewire to VGA adapter.

I'm looking for advice from seasoned Apple guys.

(Both external displays would be the same, I don't have the specs here but they're old VGA monitors with relatively low resolution)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know such device simply don't exist.